# Flow: conditional function response type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In Flow type checker, how to define function response type based on argument object property. Here is an example:

```
function test(argument) {
  if (argument.responseType === "string") {
    return "Some string value"
  }
  return { some: { json: "object" } };
}
```

Is it possible to add Flow typings to this code?

I know that it is possible to write:

```
declare export function test(argument: { responseType: string}): string | { some: { json: string } };
```

But that's not enough. I don't want an [Union Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) response. It has to be exactly string or object based on the argument provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow allows function overloading by providing [several definitions](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4305#issuecomment-353185930) to the same function. Together with [literal types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/literals/) next should work:

```
declare function test(argument: {responseType: 'string'}): string;
declare function test(argument: {}): {some: {json: string}};
```

Here is a Flow try [example code](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAKWAc2QFsRUMAueAbziIAc8iQAVAT3YgmAchIwsqCsIC+ASiZiJFANwAoUJFgIU6bHgLEylGnUYs5TZkRy1LAK2uoFGcZOnS1qsFwzw2nVG4AZRcleABeAxJSVmIA7n5BJgAiRUlkuTVvQN9-LhAAKSCAeQA5CKiyZkzVLx94EAAPQUwQYGKAaQq8wMKS0oA6a1oBhzxPAHoJ+AASAFFm8Aw5mBgcGDqchsXW4BW1mG64-JDXCiGbEFHHZSA)

Comment: @jmarceli thanks for fixing syntax issue/adding example